# Get the url of an uploaded picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is that when a user uploads a picture and presses a button I want to save the url in a database.

I have tried using: `$(#img).attr('src')` but this gives me a *really* long string.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="upload_picture">
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type='file' id="image" size="10" name="pictureURL"/>
        <img id="imageChosen" width="250px" height="250px"/>
    </label>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="order_button"">Order pic!</a>
```

JS Code:

```
$( "#order_button" ).on( "click", function() {
    var picUrl = $('#imageChosen').attr('src');
...
```

Is it possible to get the "normal" url?

**EDIT**

This was a pre-coffee question, sry. Yes the user uploads it with a local url. Maybe what I should do is generate a url of my own to the picture? Or what would the best practice be here?

Comment: But user upload local image. What url you want to get?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes you are correct.. So stupid of me. Maybe I could generate a costum url for it and upload it? What I want is  reference point when I search for the images later.

Answer (score 0):

The url you're seeing is correct - It's supposed to be like that since the image has been uploaded and not referenced ("https.google.com/yourimageid").